# javascript store values that are similar together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list that is setup like this from a sql database

```
 Team     Name    Date Joined
 TeamA    David   June 3
 TeamB    Mike    July 2
 TeamC    Mark    June 7
 TeamA    Lisa    July 2
 TeamA    Stacy   June 7
 TeamB    Tracy   July 2
 TeamC    Joe     June 3
```

I want to be able to store the list and print all the people and dates joined in TeamA or TeamB or TeamC using javascript. I am not sure how to approach this, was thinking about arrays but don't think that won't reach my goal because not sure how to combine all the items together...does anyone have ideas

Comment: Simply filter the list by the team? Arrays will suffice, try it.

Comment: In which format exactly do you have that list? Is it a TSV string?

Comment: is this list in a file of some sort or is it coming from a database? And why don't you think arrays will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your teams as array of objects:

```
var arr = [

 {"team":"TeamA", "name":"David"},
 {"team":"TeamB", "name":"Mike"},
 {"team":"TeamC", "name":"Mark"},
 {"team":"TeamA", "name":"Lisa"},
 {"team":"TeamA", "name":"Stacy"},
 {"team":"TeamB", "name":"Tracy"},
 {"team":"TeamC", "name":"Joe"}

]
```

It's flexible, you can add as many teams/people as you want. Then you can define a simple filter function:

```
var teamFilter = function(obj) {
    return obj.team == this.criteria;
}
```

And you can call it to create new filtered array like this:

```
arr.criteria = "TeamA";

var arrTeamA = arr.filter(teamFilter, arr);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6f2NN/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store the name of each team member, then you can use this:

```
var Teams = {
    TeamA: ["David", "Lisa", "Stacy"],
    TeamB: ["Mike", "Tracy"],
    TeamC: ["Mark", "Joe"]
};
```

If you want to print those values into the browser console

```
for (team in Teams){
    console.log(team+" : "+Teams[team].join(", "));
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way than hard coding the values..the values will change and the list is much larger?

Comment: @user990951: You can select the relevant values from your SQL database, serialize them to JSON and insert that dynamically in a script.

Comment: @user990951 I believe grouping the team names into keys would make it efficient during data retrieval.